# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError Android Studio Unity

Tags: java, c#, android-studio, unity-game-engine, ffmpeg

I'm having some troubles when I try to generate a library that contains another one in Android Studio. First of all I am using Android Studio 2.0 and Unity 5.3.4f1. What I want to do is integrate FFMpeg in Unity so I decided to create my own library that use FFMpeg library as an intermediary. The FFMpeg library is [here](http://writingminds.github.io/ffmpeg-android-java/).

To start I created a new empty project in Android Studio and inside of it, created a new module, which will be my library, using *New->Module->Android Library* and named it "ffmpegcodec". After that I opened *build.gradle* file inside the new module folder and paste:

```
compile 'com.writingminds:FFmpegAndroid:0.3.2'
```

inside dependencies brackets, and click *Sync* (It did not show any error).

After that create a new Java Class inside *src/main/java/package-name/* and named it *FFMpegCodec*. Inside this paste this code:

```
public class FFMpegCodec {
private static FFmpeg ffmpeg;
private static Context context;
private static FFMpegCodec INSTANCE = null;

public FFMpegCodec(){
    INSTANCE = this;
}

public static FFMpegCodec instance(){
    if(INSTANCE == null){
        INSTANCE = new FFMpegCodec();
    }
    return INSTANCE;
}

public void setContext(Context ctx){
    this.context = ctx;
}

public void loadFFMpegBinary() {
    try {
        if (ffmpeg == null) {

            ffmpeg = FFmpeg.getInstance(context);
        }
        ffmpeg.loadBinary(new LoadBinaryResponseHandler() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure() {
                Log.e("FFMPEG", "ffmpeg : NOT correct Loaded");
            }

            @Override
            public void onSuccess() {
                Log.e("FFMPEG", "ffmpeg : correct Loaded");
            }
        });
    } catch (FFmpegNotSupportedException e) {

    } catch (Exception e) {

    }
}

public void execFFmpegCommand(final String[] command) {
    try {
        ffmpeg.execute(command, new ExecuteBinaryResponseHandler() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(String s) {
                Log.e("FFMPEG", "FAILED with output : " + s);
            }

            @Override
            public void onSuccess(String s) {
                Log.e("FFMPEG", "SUCCESS with output : " + s);
            }

            @Override
            public void onProgress(String s) {
                Log.e("FFMPEG", "Started command : ffmpeg " + command);
                Log.e("FFMPEG", "progress : " + s);
            }

            @Override
            public void onStart() {
                Log.e("FFMPEG", "Started command : ffmpeg " + command);

            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
                Log.e("FFMPEG", "Finished command : ffmpeg " + command);

            }
        });
    } catch (FFmpegCommandAlreadyRunningException e) {
        // do nothing for now
    }
}
```

It basically generates an instance of FFmpeg and makes calls of ffmpeg commands.

Once I have my lib done I decided to test it in my project so I include my lib in my app graddle using:

```
compile project(':ffmpegcodec')
```

After that I just paste this code to my MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

FFMpegCodec ffmpeg;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button execCommandButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.execCommandButton);

    ffmpeg = FFMpegCodec.instance();


    execCommandButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "This is a Toast!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            ffmpeg.setContext(MainActivity.this);
            ffmpeg.loadFFMpegBinary();
            String []cmd = new String[1];
            cmd[0] = "-version";
            ffmpeg.execFFmpegCommand(cmd);
        }
    });

}
```

After that, I run my project and when I press the button it returns that everythings its ok, showing ffmpeg version. 
Once I have check that my lib works I decide to move it to Unity so copy the *ffmpegcodec-realese.arr* file inside *ffmpegcodec/build/outputs/aar* folder and paste it into my Unity project. Then I wrote an C# script to use my lib that contains this:

```
    using System;
    using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
    using UnityEngine;
    using System.Collections;
    using System.Diagnostics;

    public class ScreenRecorder {

    private AndroidJavaObject unityActivity = null;
    private AndroidJavaObject captureObject = null;

        // Use this for initialization
        public ScreenRecorder () {
            try{

                using (AndroidJavaClass unityPlayerActivityClass = new AndroidJavaClass("com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer")) {
                    unityActivity = unityPlayerActivityClass.GetStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("currentActivity");
                }

                AndroidJavaClass captureClass = new AndroidJavaClass ("com.promineostudios.ffmpegcodec.FFMpegCodec");
                if (captureClass != null) {
                    captureObject = captureClass.CallStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("instance");
                    captureObject.Call("setContext", unityActivity);
                    captureObject.Call("loadFFMpegBinary");
                }
            }catch(Exception ex){
                UnityEngine.Debug.Log(ex);
            }
        }

    }
```

The problems comes here. When I create a class instance using:

```
AndroidJavaClass captureClass = new AndroidJavaClass ("com.promineostudios.ffmpegcodec.FFMpegCodec");
```

It creates an instance correctly, and also when I create an object using:

```
captureObject = captureClass.CallStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("instance");
```

But when I try to get access to FFMpeg library methods like in "setContext" it fails and returns this:

```
UnityEngine.AndroidJavaException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/github/hiteshsondhi88/libffmpeg/FFmpeg;
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/github/hiteshsondhi88/libffmpeg/FFmpeg;
  at com.promineostudios.ffmpegcodec.FFMpegCodec.loadFFMpegBinary(FFMpegAndroidCodec.java:39)
  at com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer.nativeRender(Native Method)
  at com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer.a(Unknown Source)
  at com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer$b.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.github.hiteshsondhi88.libffmpeg.FFmpeg" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.promineostudios.ffmpegmodule-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.promineostudios.ffmpegmodule-1/lib/arm, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
  at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
  at com.promineostudios.ffmpegcodec.FFMpegCodec.loadFFMpegBinary(FFMpegAndroidCodec.java:39) 
  at com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer.nativeRender(Native Method) 
  at com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer.a(Unknown Source) 
  at com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer$b.run(Unknown Source)
```

I think that the problem is in when I export my lib into Unity but I do not know what is going wrong. If anybody could help me I will be really appreciated.

Thanks and excuse me for my English.

Comment: we ran into a similar problem and were wondering how you resolved this.

Comment: Hi @uchamp, I could not find out how to solve it. If you find a way to make it works I will be really appreciated if you share it. I'm sorry for not being able to help you.

Comment: Have you tried also copying the .jar file that contains "com.github.hiteshsondhi88.libffmpeg" classes into unity plugins folder?

Comment: is the problem solved? I am also facing the same issue.
@RandomCouch Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi, I'm not longer working on this project and we didn't get a solution. Sorry

Comment: @Siddharth-Verma I just posted an answer to this, I hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

I know you're no longer working on this project Nestoraj, however I have figured out a solution:

1. The error you're getting is caused by the UnityPlayerActivity not finding the source for com/github/hiteshsondhi88/libffmpeg/FFmpeg so in order to fix that you must put the 'com.writingminds:FFmpegAndroid:0.3.2' jar file inside your Unity project's Assets/Plugins/Android folder
2. After doing that and running the project, you're still going to get an error loading the ffmpeg binary file, this is because it's also not properly packaged in Unity, to fix this you need to export your project to Gradle/Android Studio, and then inside your src/main/jniLibs directory you have to place the ffmpeg .so binary files, according to each architecture so jniLibs/armeabi-v7a/libARM_ARCH.so  jniLibs/armeabi/libARM_ARCH.so etc. Then you must also place the ffmpeg object files inside src/main/assets and again according to each architecture like so : src/main/assets/armeabi-v7a/ffmpeg etc.

Once those 2 steps are done you should be able to run your project in Android Studio and load the ffmpeg binary inside your Unity project