# How to resolve java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError in Unity android plugin

Tags: java, android-studio, unity-game-engine

I am trying to make an android plugin for my Unity project that displays a notification bar with some actions. I export the android plugin as an AAR file and import it into Unity. This was all working fine, up until just yesterday when I wrote in some minor new features. I built the module, re-imported the aar into unity, and pushed to a device, only to get this error when the app tries to instantiate a NotificationCompat.Builder:

`java java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroid/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat$Builder`

The strange thing is that prior to yesterday the notification was working just fine, and I have no idea how code I changed could result in a run-time error like this. I have somehow messed up the integration pipeline from my plugin to Unity, and have no idea how I caused it or how to fix it.

I have seen [related posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36912856/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-android-studio-unity) that claim you need to manually inject dependent libraries from the sdk into unity. However, I find this hard to believe because it was working fine and I have never had to do any of that. I did go ahead and try sticking "support-v4-25.3.1.aar" from the sdk into the plugins folder, but to no avail, same error on trying to display the notification.

Here's the basic setup:

MyService.java:

```java
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;
...

 public void showNotification(){
        mNotificationManager.cancelAll();


            int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH;
            NotificationChannel mChannel = mNotificationManager.getNotificationChannel(id);
            if (mChannel == null) {
                mChannel = new NotificationChannel(id, title, importance);
                mChannel.setSound(null, null);
                mNotificationManager.createNotificationChannel(mChannel);
            }

            NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext(),id);
            builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.audiotilesplayer_notification);
            builder.setContentTitle("MyApp");
            builder.setContentText("App is running");
            builder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
            builder.addAction(buttonID, "Do Some Action",
                    buttonPendingIntent);
            Notification noti = builder.build();
            mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFY_ID, builder.build());

    }
...
```

And the module's build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28



    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation files('libs/classes.jar')
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0'
}
```

The app crashes on `java NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext(),id);` with the described error. What's very curious to me is that this is a runtime error and not a compile time error... I don't quite understand the mechanics of unity-android plugins, but missing a class definition sounds like something that should fail at compile time (unless this is some funky reflection shenanigans unity is doing to push off resolution?). I have been pulling my hair out over how this could have gotten messed up when I have changed nothing about my build process, any advice greatly appreciated!

Comment: Hello are you still having trouble with this?

Comment: Hi, no I just stopped using NotificationCompat and am just using Notification with a build version check for Oreo or above and build it with two different sets of code. probably is not the best solution for compatability with lower version of android, but was the best I could do

Comment: I just ask because i was having a similar class not found error. I ended up resolving mine by generating an .aar file instead of a jar.  Placing some dependencies directly in my assets/plugins/android folder.   This may be the dependency you need to get it to work (https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/android.support/compatibility-v4/19.1.0). Also if you decide to change your plugin from jar to and .aar file, you must change ``implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')`` to ``compileOnly fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')`` in your module gradle file

Comment: Thanks for the tip! Actually I am already using an aar file, and I've also found I need to go in to the aar and delete the "classes.jar" or else the Unity build fails with complains about multiple class definitions. Maybe I'm putting something in the wrong place...

Comment: Go in you're gradle file and change  ``implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')`` to ``compileOnly fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')``. Then you don't have to go in and delete the ``classes.jar`` file as it won't include it in the generated .aar file

Answer (score 0):

Encountered same issue. Managed to fix it by copying dependencies from Android Studio to Unity mainTemplate.gradle. The dependencies I had to copy were

- implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.0'
- implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0'

Here is how my how mainTemplate.gradle looks on empty unity project, with just android plugin. Unity 2019.3, enabled mainTemplate from publishing settings.

```
    // GENERATED BY UNITY. REMOVE THIS COMMENT TO PREVENT OVERWRITING WHEN EXPORTING AGAIN

apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
**APPLY_PLUGINS**

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0'
**DEPS**}

android {
    compileSdkVersion **APIVERSION**
    buildToolsVersion '**BUILDTOOLS**'

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion **MINSDKVERSION**
        targetSdkVersion **TARGETSDKVERSION**
        ndk {
            abiFilters **ABIFILTERS**
        }
        versionCode **VERSIONCODE**
        versionName '**VERSIONNAME**'
        consumerProguardFiles 'proguard-unity.txt'**USER_PROGUARD**
    }

    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }

    aaptOptions {
        ignoreAssetsPattern = "!.svn:!.git:!.ds_store:!*.scc:.*:!CVS:!thumbs.db:!picasa.ini:!*~"
    }**PACKAGING_OPTIONS**
}**REPOSITORIES****SOURCE_BUILD_SETUP**
**EXTERNAL_SOURCES**
```